# How do I convert tar.bz2 to tar.gz?

Tags: linux, compression, tar, bzip2

I'm new in Linux, is this conversion possible?

Do I need to compress and decompress all content?

Comment: You might consider using `xz` instead of `gzip` as it can compress better at the expense of using more time and memory.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
bunzip2 -c < file.tar.bz2 | gzip -c > file.tar.gz
```

Comment: this is nice too! :-)

Comment: And GZ to BZip2: `gunzip -c < file.tar.gz | bzip2 -c > file.tar.bz2`

Comment: Also consider `gzip -9 -c ...` for tighter compression.

Answer (score 6):

You need to decompress, and then compress.

You can convert like so:

```
 bunzip2 -c -d file.tar.bz2 | gzip -v9 > file.tar.gz
```

Comment: this is nice! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to decompress and compress the content (because compression is not "compositional").