# How to convert .tar.gz to .tar.xz?

Tags: linux, unix, compression, tar

How to convert `.tar.gz` to `.tar.xz`?

I have a bunch of `.tar.gz` files that I would like to convert to `.tar.xz` for a better compression.

How to do this efficiently? A command like this would be great: [How do I convert tar.bz2 to tar.gz?](https://superuser.com/questions/357978/how-do-i-convert-tar-bz2-to-tar-gz).

Here are the two commands I'm using to create a tar gz and tar xz:

- TAR GZ `tar czf folder.tar.gz folder`
- TAR XZ (LZMA) `tar cfJ folder.tar.xz folder`

Is there a better way than: `tar xvzf folder.tar.gz && tar cfJ folder.tar.xz folder && rm -rf folder`?

Comment: This is a better question for [unix.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That command in your nearly duplicate question can be modified to use `gunzip` as a decompressor and `xz` to achieve exactly the same result.

```
gunzip2 -c < file.tar.gz | xz -c -T0 > file.tar.xz
```

`-c` in both cases tells the program to output to `stdout`. In the case of `gunzip` it receives data from `stdin` via `< file.tar.gz` and is then piped (`|`) to `xz`. `xz` then is told the same, with its output piped to your output file.
`-T0` is there to leverage parallel compression to reduce the operation time significantly.

`gunzip` should be effectively the same as `gzip -d`

Comment: what is `gunzip2`? I can only find `gunzip`

Answer (score 2):

The incantation you seek is:

```
gzip -cd file.tar.gz | xz > file.tar.xz
rm file.tar.gz
```

If you have many CPU cores and want maximum possible compression:

```
gzip -cd file.tar.gz | pxz -9 > file.tar.xz
rm file.tar.gz
```